# Kerberos multi-hop delegation through PowerShell and Python to SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, kerberos

I've got an SSIS package which runs using the SQL Server Agent account (also has an AD account) on which I've enabled Kerberos delegation.

I've set all the permissions (`Set-ExecutionPolicy` for PowerShell, etc.) on the file systems to run the necessary scripts, but trying to access the SQL server using a DSN gives me the `ANONYMOUS LOGON` error. Do I need to enable delegation somewhere in between? Is there an argument I need to provide to PyODBC? The ODBC connetion is set to use `Trusted_Connection` already.

Workflow:

Server A:

SQL Server Agent > SSIS Package > Execute Process > PowerShell Script >

Server B:

Python script on remote server > query SQL database on Server A

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the Delegation tab of the SQL Server Agent Active Directory account (with the "Expanded" checkbox marked).